# How to distinguish the user's intent with .automatic DropProposal int iOS 11

Tags: ios, drag

I have an application that is suitable for the .automatic intent in UIDropProposal. Like this:

```
UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .automatic)
```

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out what the user intended? Did he intend to insert the data into a new cell or just overwrite an existing cell. All the animation works fine.

But in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
```

I need to be able to tell what the user finally intended.

How can this be done?

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`coordinator.proposal.intent` should provide the `UITableViewDropIntent` and have chosen between `insertAtDestinationIndexPath` and `insertIntoDestinationIndexPath` if `.automatic` was specified in `tableView(:dropSessionDidUpdate)`. The WWDC video says table view will pick between the two. Haven't progressed enough to verify it yet, though.